# How do I perform an action on each element of  a List and return the result (without affecting the original of course)?

Tags: java, list, generics

How do I write a static method in Java that will take a List, perform an action on each element, and return the result (without affecting the original of course)?

For example, if I want to add 2 to each element what goes in the ... here? The concrete return type must be the same, e.g. if my List is a LinkedList with values 1,2,3 I should get back a LinkedList with values 3,4,5. Similarly for ArrayList, Vector, Stack etc, which are all Lists.

I can see how to do this using multiple `if (lst instanceof LinkedList) ...` etc... any better way?

```
import java.util.List;

public class ListAdd {       

    static List<Integer> add2 (List<Integer> lst) {

    ...

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Brandon: How would he copy the list, though?

Comment: @Luigi: Would using reflection be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @thkala: He should be able to use the Collections.copy(List,List) method.

Comment: @Brandon: Collections.copy(List,List) requires that *you provide* the destination list - an actual instance of the class that you need.

Comment: @thkala: Understood. And...I see your point. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @thkala If reflection is the cleanest way to do it, it's acceptable

Comment: do you not want to manipulate the original `List` or the original objects in the `List`?

Comment: your title is misleading. I would usually take "perform an action" to mean something that is done purely for side-effects (e.g. print). Here, you want to transform each element into a new value and collect the results into a new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well someone mentioned reflection. It seems to be an elegant solution:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ListAdd {

    static List<Integer> add2 (List<Integer> lst) throws Exception {

        List<Integer> result = lst.getClass().newInstance();
        for (Integer i : lst) result.add(i + 2);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Concise, but it thows an checked exception, which is not nice.

Also, wouldn't it be nicer if we could use the method on concrete types as well, e.g. if `a` is an `ArrayList` with values 1, 2, 3, we could call `add2(a)` and get an `ArrayList` back? So in an improved version, we could make the signature generic:

```
static <T extends List<Integer>> T add2 (T lst) {
    T res;
    try {
        res = (T) lst.getClass().newInstance();

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    for (Integer i : lst) res.add(i + 2);
    return res;
}
```

I think throwing a runtime exception is the least worst option if a list without a nullary construcor is passed in. I don't see a way to ensure that it does. (Java 8 type annotations to the rescue maybe?) Returning `null` would be kind of useless.

The downside of using this signature is that we can't return an `ArrayList` etc as the *default*, as we could have done as an alternative to throwing an exception, since the return type is guaranteed to be the same type as that passed in. However, if the user actually wants an ArrayList (or some other default type) back, he can make an ArrayList copy and use the method on that.

If anyone with API design experience reads this, I would be interested to know your thoughts on which is the preferable option: 1) returning a List that needs to be explicity cast back into the original type, but enabling a return of a different concrete type, or 2) ensuring the return type is the same (using generics), but risking exceptions if (for example) a singleton object without a nullary constructor is passed in?

Answer (score 6):

There are already many answers, but I'd like to show you a different way to think of this problem.

The operation you want to perform is known as `map` in the world of functional programming. It is something we do really all the time in functional languages.

Let `M<A>` be some kind of container (in your case, `M` would be `List`, and `A` would be `Integer`; however, the container can be lots of other things). Suppose you have a *function* that transforms `A`s into `B`s, that is, `f: A -> B`. Let's write this function as of type `F<A, B>`, to use a notation closer to Java. Note that you can have `A = B`, as in the example you give (in which `A = B = Integer`).

Then, the operation `map` is defined as follows:

```
M<B> map(M<A>, F<A, B>)
```

That is, the operation will return a `M<B>`, presumably by applying `F<A, B>` to each `A` in `M<A>`.

### In practice...

There's a brilliant library developed by Google, called [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which brings lot's of functional idioms to Java.

In Guava, the `map` operation is called `transform`, and it can operate on any `Iterable`. It has also more specific implementations that work directly on lists, sets, etc.

Using Guava, the code you want to write would look like this:

```
static List<Integer> add2(List<Integer> ns) {
  return Lists.transform(ns, new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override Integer apply(Integer n) { return n + 2; }
  }
}
```

Simple as that.

This code won't touch the original list, it will simply provide a new list that calculates its values as needed (that is, the values of the newly created list won't be calculated unless needed -- it's called a *lazy operation*).

As a final consideration, it is not possible for you to be absolutely sure that you will be able to return exactly the same implementation of List. And as many others pointed out, unless there's a very specific reason for this, you shouldn't really care. That's why List is an interface, you don't care about the implementation.

Comment: Very nice, I'll have to try Guava out.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the `List` interface doesn't make any guarantees that you'll have a way to duplicate it.

You may have some luck with various techniques:

- Using `clone()` on the passed in `List`, although it may throw, or (since it is protected in `Object`) simply not be accessible
- Use reflection to look for a public no-argument constructor on the passed-in `List`
- Try to serialize and deserialize it in order to perform a "deep clone"
- Create some sort of factory and build in knowledge of how to duplicate each different kind of List your code may encounter  (What if it's a wrapper created by `unmodifiableList()`, or some oddball custom implementation backed by a `RandomAccessFile`?)
- If all else fails, either throw, or return an `ArrayList` or a `Vector` for lack of better options

Comment: The problem is that `clone()` is not public in `List` (or any of its supertypes). So we still have to cast to some type which supports it, or use reflection.

Comment: I've tried cloning, but it doesn't seem to be possible. If you make the static method generic, to take a type `<T extends List, AbstractList>` you have the problem that neither `AbstractList` nor any supertypes implement a `clone()` method... AbstractList isn't Cloneable, and Object just doesn't.

Comment: ... despite the fact that all the concrete classes of List in the collections API are actually Cloneable :(

Comment: @Luigi Plinge: all public ones

Comment: @Luigi Plinge: and implementing Cloneable does not necessarily mean it supports `clone()`

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using an interface, in this case `List`, is to abstract the fact that the implementation is hidden behind the interface.

Your intention is clear to me, however: the `Clonable` interface supports creating a new instance with the same state. This interface might not be defined on your `List`.

Often it's a good idea to rethink this situation: why do you need to clone the `List` in this place, this class? Shouldn't your list-creator be responsible for cloning the list? Or shouldn't the caller, who knows the type, make sure he passes in a clone of his list?

Probably, if you look for the semantics as you defined it, you can implement all your supported `List`s:

```
static Vector<Integer> addTwo(Vector<Integer> vector) {
    Vector<Integer> copy = null; // TODO: copy the vector
    return addTwo_mutable(copy);
}
static ArrayList<Integer> addTwo(ArrayList<Integer> aList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> copy = null; // TODO: copy the array list
    return addTwo_mutable(copy);
}
static LinkedList<Integer> addTwo(LinkedList<Integer> lList) {
    LinkedList<Integer> copy = null; // TODO: copy the linked list
    return addTwo_mutable(copy);
}

private <T extends List<Integer>> static T addTwo_mutable(T list) {
    return list; // TODO: implement
}
```

Even, when you don't support a data-type, you'll get a nice compiler error that the specified method does not exists.

<sup>(code not tested)</sup>

Comment: `Cloneable` doesn't actually make the `clone()` method accessible -- it just means the `protected` method `clone()` performs a shallow copy instead of throwing.

Comment: "By convention, classes that implement this interface should override `Object.clone` (which is protected) with a public method." I remembered it as "you **should** override `Object.clone`," but you are absolutely right, Jeffrey!

Comment: That's certainly one approach. I always wondered why Arrays.sort() mutated your current list rather than returning a new sorted one - maybe this is why.

Comment: The three classes there all implement a public clone method, but declare it as returning `Object` instead of its own type. :-(  It is probably easier to use the copy-constructor on each (but this will ignore eventual subclasses).

Comment: Working with immutable data-structures is generally not *the* standard in Java. In functional programming languages, they are a lot more common (see Clojure).

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to look for a public zero-arg constructor on the result of lst.getClass() and then invoke() it to obtain the List into which you'll place your results. The Java Collections Framework recommends that any derivative of Collection offer a zero-arg constructor. That way, your results we be of the same runtime class as the argument.

Comment: Any *general purpose* collection, not every collection. (For example, the classes of the collection views of maps will not have such an constructor, neither the internal classes implementing List.subList.)

Comment: Sounds good. I'm not really familiar with reflection though. If someone could show how this is done it would be be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant which does neither copies nor modifies the original list. Instead, it wraps the original list by another object.

```
public List<Integer> add2(final List<Integer> lst) {
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
        public int size() {
            return lst.size();
        }
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return 2 + lst.get(index);
        }
    };
}
```

The returned list is not modifiable, but will change whenever the original list changes.
(This implements the iterator based on index access, thus it will be slow for a linked list. Then better implement it based on AbstractSequentialList.)

Of course, the resulting list will obviously **not be of the same class as the original list**.

Use this solution only if you really only need a read-only *two added* view of your original list, not if you want a modified copy with similar properties.

Comment: Great idea! However I would add *bounds checking* to it, for safety.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: The bounds checking is done by `lst.get(index)`, no need to duplicate it here.

Comment: Interesting way to make a view on your list! Thanks. Although not exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you that what you want to do is not possible in the general case, consider the following class:

```
final class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
  private MyList() {
    super.add(1);
    super.add(2);
    super.add(3);
  }
  private static class SingletonHolder {
    private static final MyList instance = new MyList();
  }
  public static MyList getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.instance;
  }
}
```

It is a singleton (also, a lazy, thread-safe singleton by the way), it's only instance can be obtained from `MyList.getInstance()`. You cannot use reflection reliably (because the constructor is private; for you to use reflection, you'd have to rely on proprietary, non-standard, non-portable APIs, or on code that could break due to a SecurityManager). So, there's no way for you to return a new instance of this list, with different values.

It's `final` as well, so that you cannot return a child of it.

Also, it would be possible to override every method of ArrayList that would modify the list, so that it would be really an immutable singleton.

Now, why would you want to return the exact same implementation of List?

Comment: In this case I wouldn't, but in the general case there are reasons (mainly performance) that Lists are implemented in different ways. The idea is that I have 1 method that I can use for all List types. I guess maybe my method signature should be `static <T extends List<Integer>> T add2 (T lst)` instead. Regarding not being able to use getInstance() for the singleton, I can just catch the resulting exception in the method and return an ArrayList for cases like this.